# Git fetch/pull does not update local repository even though there are changes on origin

Tags: git

I have a git repository on my local machine tracking a remote repository (origin) on github. There are 5 days of changes on github on the master branch, yet when I enter `git pull origin master` or even `git fetch` I get a message saying everything is up to date even though it isn't. I think the issue may go back to a rebase that messed up that I didn't abort out of. Does anyone have any clues how I can get my local repository to update with the changes on origin?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a merge?

`git merge origin master`

Comment: In the end I realised that I had done `git push -f` which wiped out the changes on origin. So I just found another branch with the correct history and did another `git push -f`.